# Perform a log-out using stormpath $http

Tags: express, stormpath

I am trying to revoke oauth2 tokens using the stormpath API. Server-side authentication is performed using stormpath + express. Here is my request.

```js
    function revokeOauthTokens(params) {
      // Revoke the oauth2 access. and refresh tokens
      var oauthLogoutReq = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: params.apiBaseUrl + '/logout',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data:  'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='
          + params.oauth_tokens.refresh_token
      }
      return $http(oauthLogoutReq);
    }
```

Where `apiBaseUrl` is my nodejs base url and `ouath_tokens` contains the response granted by a request to `/oauth/token` endpoint.

Looking at the documentation at the following links leaves me confused.

- http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/logout.html
- http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/token-management/

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there!  I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) so I can certainly help here.  Can you tell me if you're using our `express-stormpath` library (which manages the tokens via cookies), or if you're integrating more directly, e.g.s manually creating tokens with the /oauth/token endpoint the Stormpath provides?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm manually creating tokens via oauth/tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I have to show you how to do this with a code sample, which I'm putting together now.  I'll follow up with an answer when ready.

Comment: My backend is based on express-stormpath. But I'm also making a lot of API calls using the oauth2 tokens and I'd like to revoke their access directly. I'm aware of the fact that the express library manages the tokens via cookies, but this approach is not feasible in my case because my front-end is based on electron.io which does not always act like a regular browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.  As you’ve seen, express-stormpath is using secure, http-only cookies for token storage, and this doesn’t work for Cordova, Electron, etc, where cookie storage isn't implemented to spec.  The alternative is local storage, or some other storage API that is provided to you (hopefully a secure one!).

The express-stormpath library does provide a `/logout` route, and it does revoke tokens, but it’s looking for the tokens in cookies.  We need to add a new route, likely `/oauth/revoke`, to support explicit token revocation.

This is pretty easy to add right now as a custom route handler, and I’m including a link below.  But please be aware that **express-stormpath uses local token validation by default**.  This is done for speed (no roundtrip to our API) but the caveat is that your local server will NOT know that the tokens have been revoked, and can technically still be used for authentication if a malicious third party has stolen them from your client.  If this is a concern you want to to address, you should opt-in to `stormpath` validation, which will always require a check against our token database.  This is documented here:

http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/authentication.html#token-validation-strategy

All that said, here is the route handler that you could wire up as `/oauth/revoke`, and have your Electron client use it to revoke the tokens when the user logs out:

```
'use strict';

var revokeToken = require('express-stormpath/lib/helpers/revoke-token');

function defaultResponder(res, err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); // or your system logger
    return res.status(err.status || 400).json({
      message: err.developerMessage || err.message
    });
  }
  res.end();
}

/**
 * Implements the expected behavior of the /oauth/revoke endpoint, and requires
 * that token_type be defined.  This assumes that you are using the express-stormpath
 * module, so that your Stormpath client and configuration context is available.
 *
 * @param {Object<ExpressRequest>}  req     Express JS Request
 * @param {Object<ExpressResponse>} res     Express JS Response
 */
function revokeTokens(req, res){

  var client = req.app.get('stormpathClient');
  var config = req.app.get('stormpathConfig');
  var secret = config.client.apiKey.secret;
  var token = req.body.token;
  var token_type = req.body.token_type;

  if (!token || ! token_type) {
    defaultResponder(res, {
      message: 'token and token_type fields are required'
    });
  }

  if (token_type === 'access_token') {
    revokeToken.revokeAccessToken(client, token, secret, defaultResponder.bind(null, res));
  } else if (token_type === 'refresh_token') {
    revokeToken.revokeRefreshToken(client, token, secret, defaultResponder.bind(null, res));
  } else {
    defaultResponder(res, {
      message: 'invalid token_type'
    });
  }
}


module.exports = revokeTokens;
```

If you find that you don't want to use express-stormpath and would like to use something more direct, you can drop down to the [Stormpath Node SDK](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/jsdoc/) and use it for token revocation:

https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/jsdoc/AccessToken.html

Or you can make DELETE requests directly against our API:

https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/auth_n.html#revoking-access-and-refresh-tokens

In both cases, you would be doing that from your server, not the Electron application.

I hope this helps!

-Robert